# recordform is not showing all fields on clicking different buttons

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-record-form

I have created a beer explorer using aura components. So below I have created a Explorer parent component and added beer list component as child and in this I am adding beerdetails as child. So when I search for beers list of beer records will come. In each beer record I am including view details button. When I click on that button it will get the recordId from List Component and passing it to beerlist recordId attribute and then on button click event getting recordId and usign recordForm displaying details. On UI, When clicking on single record details button, i'm able to get recordform details. Then clicking on any other button in list of records, i am only getting Name, and no other fields are displaying. How to solve this. I have also attached screenshots.

```
BeerList component:
-----------------
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="recordList" type="object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="beerId" type="string"/>
       <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.recordList}" var="item">
            <div class="slds col slds-size_1-of-4 slds-p-around_x-small">
                
                <lightning:card title="{!item.Name}" footer="{!item.brewery_Name__c}"
                                iconName="custom:custom56">
                    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                            <div class="slds col slds-size_1-of-3">
                                <img src="{!$Resource.BeerImage2}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds col slds-size_2-of-3">
                                Name: {!item.Name}<br/>
                                Id: {!item.Id__c}<br/>
                                Alcohol %: {!item.Alcohol__c}
                            </div>   
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <aura:set attribute="actions">
                        <lightning:button value="{!item.Id}" label="Details" variant="Brand" 
                                          onclick="{!c.showInfo}"/>
                    </aura:set>
                </lightning:card>
               </div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
        <c:BeerDetails recordId="{!v.beerId}"/>
   </aura:component>
```

### BeerList component JS:

```
BeerList component Js:
---------------- 

({
    showInfo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var eventSource = event.getSource().get("v.value")
       // var eventSource = event.getSource();
       // var beerObj=eventSource.get('v.value');
        console.log(eventSource);
        component.set('v.beerId', eventSource);
    }
    
})
```

```
BeerDetails Component:
--------------------

<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldsArray" type="List" default="['Name', 'Alcohol__c', 'Id__c', 'brewery_id__c', 'Price__c', 'brewery_Name__c']"/>
    <lightning:card>
    <div class="slds-p-around_small">
        <lightning:recordForm
            aura:id="myRecordForm"
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            objectApiName="Beer__c"
            layoutType="Compact"
            columns="2"
            mode="view"
            fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"
        />
        <div class="slds-p-around_small">
            <lightning:button label="Order Now" value="Order Now" variant="brand" 
                              onclick="{!c.doOrder}" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </lightning:card>    
</aura:component>
```

```
Screenshots:
```

[image: Recordform with fields on button click][image: Recordform without fields on button click]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layoutType instead of "Compact", use "Full". It will solve the problem.

```html
<lightning:recordForm
    aura:id="myRecordForm"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    objectApiName="Beer__c"
    layoutType="Full"
    columns="2"
    mode="view"
    fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"
/>
```